# Serialization of Class-Based Object Under Rails Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, serialization, ruby-on-rails-7

Consider the concept of a "score translator": given a (numerical) score in a test, the translator takes the score as an input and returns a verbal evaluation. An example for such translation can be displayed as either table or mathematical function:

| From | To | Verbal Eval |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 59 | F |
| 60 | 64 | E |
| 65 | 74 | D |
| 75 | 84 | C |
| 85 | 94 | B |
| 95 | 100 | A |

or

[image: math representation of the score translation function]

---

The basic setting is this: I have an `Exam` model, which relates to a relevant DB table. For each instance of exam, I have a different "score translator" (because, for example, different faculties have different passing thresholds). Easily enough, I could represent the translator as a DB-related model, add the relevant association with `has_one` and `belongs_to` and that's it. That's the easy way.

The harder way is not using a model for translator. It is a relatively simple object, with a single function and the data as an array of hashes: `[{from: 0, to: 59, verbal: F},...,{from: 95, to: 100, verbal: A}`

```
class ScoreTranslator
  
  def initialize()
    @levels = []
  end
  
  def add_eval_level(from_score, to_score, verbal_eval)
    @levels << {from: from_score, to: to_score, verbal: verbal_eval}
  end

  def translate(score)
    verbal=nil
    if @levels.present?
      @levels.each do |l|
        verbal = l.verbal if ((score >= l.from) && (score <= l.to))
      end
    end
    return verbal
end
```

So hypothetically, I can define a variable named "translator" inside the `Exam` model, which is serialized to JSON (or YAML, or whatever), then store each translator instance under the relevant Exam record.

A. Does this (=serializing the object rather than creating a table) make any sense?

B. Could it work?

C. Which serializer should I use? I've read [this](https://blog.kiprosh.com/serialization_in_ruby_on_rails_part_one/) and remained unconvinced

D. Is this considered a fair practice, or is it a really bad one?

Answer (score 0):

Your data model isn't complex, so storing it as a "score lookup" table (with three columns, plus an association to the `exams` table) would be trivial. You could also add validation in the model to prevent overlapping ranges. Given that, mapping a score to its "verbal" equivalent would be trivial (find me the first record where the score is between the 'from' and 'to'.

Serializers are fine if you have document-like data (e.g. stuff that has no explicit schema). For something like this I think it would be overkill.

Word of warning: `eval` is a Kernel method and, though you are using it as a symbol here, you may get unstuck if you try to have a Model attribute with that name.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Besides that, I am fully aware of the trivial solution, but am not interested in implementing it (as I wrote in the post)

Comment: Ah I understand. Some feedback then: your loop in `translate` could be made more efficient by just calling return once you have found a match, as it will continue even once `verbal` has a value set. You could also define the scores internally as ranges (`@levels << {range: from..to, verbal: verbal_eval}` ) and test if a score belongs to the range ( `l.verbal if l.range.include?(score)` )

Comment: But to answer your questions directly: A IMHO it seems a complicated solution for no apparent benefit, B yes it could work, C if you are using Postgres you could just store is as a JSON or JSONB field (no serialization required) and D anything that looks like a table should probably _be_ a table, unless there's a sound business or technical reason not to go that way. Again, just my opinion. But given you're doing this in Rails it makes sense to follow the patterns already laid out.